# java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'View RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-room

Estaba desarrollando una App en Android con Java en la que tengo una BBDD local con Room en la que almaceno una descripcion y una url de una imagen, que despues pretendo pintar en un RecycleView que tiene un TextView con un Imageview.

Creo que puede estar relacionado con la forma en la que interactua con los datos y la vista el holder del recycle, aunque no tengo mucha idea tampoco.

Mi problema esq al realizar la consulta a la BBD y tratar de levantar el recycleView con los datos que recuperio obtengo el siguiente error:

```
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'android.view.View androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$ViewHolder.itemView' on a null object reference
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7079)
```

El código del fragment es el siguiente:

```
package com.example.journal.ui.journal;

import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.journal.R;
import com.example.journal.SQLiteImplementation.BirdRoom;
import com.example.journal.SQLiteImplementation.Birddb;

import java.lang.reflect.Array;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.List;

import static com.example.journal.R.id.item_imgDiario;


public class JournalFragment extends Fragment {
    private RecyclerView recycleView;
    private JournalViewModel mViewModel;
    private TextView txtTitulo, txtHora;
    private ImageView itemJornal;
    private BirdRoom[] birds;
    private List<BirdRoom> birdList;
    public static JournalFragment newInstance() {
        return new JournalFragment();
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container,
                             @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_journal, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        //birds = new List<BirdRoom>();

        itemJornal = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.item_imgDiario);
        txtTitulo = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTituloDiario);
        txtHora = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtHora);
        // RECOVER THE DATA FROM THE CAPTURE FRAGMENT.
        //TODO: Creo que lo que recupere el Jornal debeía ser desde la BBDD local de Room, ya que desde un Bundle siempre va a llegar Null.
        //TODO: Crear uno hilo para hacer la consulta a la BBDD.

        //Set the hour.
        Calendar calendario = Calendar.getInstance();
        int hora, minutos, segundos,dia, mes, annio;
        String mes_string;
        hora =calendario.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)+2;
        minutos = calendario.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
        segundos = calendario.get(Calendar.SECOND);
        mes = calendario.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        dia = calendario.get(Calendar.DATE);
        annio = calendario.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        switch (mes){
            case 1:
                mes_string = "ENERO";
                break;
            case 2:
                mes_string = "FEBRERO";
                break;
            case 3:
                mes_string = "MARZO";
                break;
            case 4:
                mes_string = "ABRIL";
                break;
            case 5:
                mes_string = "MAYO";
                break;
            case 6:
                mes_string = "JUNIO";
                break;
            case 7:
                mes_string = "JULIO";
                break;
            case 8:
                mes_string = "AGOSTO";
                break;
            case 9:
                mes_string = "SEPTIEMBRE";
                break;
            case 10:
                mes_string = "OCTUBRE";
                break;
            case 11:
                mes_string = "NOVIEMBRE";
                break;
            case 12:
                mes_string = "DICIEMBRE";
                break;
            default:
                mes_string = "";
        }

        txtHora.setText(hora + ":" + minutos + ":" + segundos + " - " + dia + " " + mes_string + " " +  annio);
        itemJornal = (ImageView) view.findViewById(item_imgDiario);
        //itemJornal.setImageDrawable(null);

        /*
                //TODO: PROBAR A INSERTAR UNA INSTANCIA DE BIRDROOM EN LA BBDD PARA VER SI ES PORQUE NO TIENE DATOS.

         */

                //TODO: SE QUEDA LA UI COLGADA PORUQE PETA EL MAIN-THREAD

                //Set the Looper for the Toast.
        if(Looper.getMainLooper()==null){
            Looper.prepareMainLooper();
            }
        birds = new BirdRoom[100];
        requestBirds(view);
        }



    private void requestBirds(View view) {
        Birddb bd = Birddb.getDatabase(getContext());
        AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                birds = bd.birdDAO().loadAllBirds();
            }
        });
        //Recover the data from Room bbdd.



        //TODO: Cargar el recycleView en otro hilo, que no se el MainThread.

        updateUi(view);

    }



    private void updateUi(View view) {

        //TODO: SOlucionar UI bloqueda al hacer la Consulta a la BBDD.

        birdList = Arrays.asList(birds);
        if(!birdList.isEmpty()){
            //TODO: Cargar con un for, las descripciones con los ImageView a partir de la Url de la imagen.
            //TODO: Solucionar error con RecycleView.

            recycleView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
            recycleView.setHasFixedSize(true);
            recycleView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(view.getContext()));
            recycleView.setAdapter(new RecycleViewAdapter(birdList, getContext()));

        }else{
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "No se dispone de ninguna foto actualmente en su diario", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

    }
}
```

Si sabeís por donde van los tiros, y podeís ayudar, muchas gracias de ante mano!

[EDIT]

Añado el RecycleViewAdapter

```
package com.example.journal.ui.journal;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.drawable.BitmapDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.example.journal.R;
import com.example.journal.SQLiteImplementation.BirdRoom;
import com.squareup.picasso.Picasso;

import java.util.List;

public class RecycleViewAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecycleViewHolder> {
    public List<BirdRoom> bird;
    public Context context;


    public RecycleViewAdapter(List<BirdRoom> bird, Context context) {
        this.bird = bird;
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(final int position) {
        return R.layout.item_jornal;
    }


    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull RecycleViewHolder holder, int position) {

        //TODO: Averiguar como pasarle el Array de BirdRoom a la vista del RecycleView, para ligarlo a la misma.
        //Cargo la imagen de los objetos BirdRoom mediante su URL y la libreria de Picasso.
        Picasso.with(context).load(bird.get(position).url_picture).into(holder.getImgBird());
        //Cargo la descripcion de cada BirdRoom en el RecycleView.
        TextView txtDescripcion = holder.getTxtDescripcion();
        txtDescripcion.setText(bird.get(position).getDescripcion());

    }
         

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return 100;
    }
}
```

Comment: Agrega tu RecycleViewAdapter ahí es donde se provoca el problema

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El problema se genera dentro de tu Adapter llamado `RecycleViewAdapter`, estas retornando una vista con valor null:

```
  @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecycleViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        return null;
    }
```

debes asegurar que dentro de  `onCreateViewHolder()` se retorne una vista de tu clase `ViewHolder`.

Ejemplo:

```
@Override
public myViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup viewGroup, int position) {

    ....
    .... 
    return new myViewHolder(.......);
}
```

Comment: Y que debería implementar en ese método, recuperar los componentes del item view del RecycleView?? Porque no tengo el view para acceder.